# "Two terms in a row" error

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, raku

I am trying to write a compact line as below, the code is an extract from a script that reads STDIN by using the dynamically scoped special variable $*IN. Can you please advise how to write this line correctly?

**This works**

```
for $*IN.lines() {
    last when "" ;
    say "VERBOSE \"$_ is the string\"";
    $i=$i+1;
}
```

## **does not work**

```
.say "VERBOSE \"$_ is the string\"" for $*IN.lines() last when "";
```

error output:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin/agi-t1.p6
Two terms in a row
at /usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin/agi-t1.p6:5
------> .say⏏ "Verbose \"$_\"" for $*IN.lines() last
expecting any of:
  infix
  infix stopper
  statement end
  statement modifier
  statement modifier loop
```

Comment: Thanks to #perl6 irc!
timotimo the problem is that you can't combine prefix-for and postfix-for in one line like that. it's eitherlike
timotimo m: say "hi $_" for <a b c d>
camelia cbb5ee5f9: OUTPUT: «hi a␤hi b␤hi c␤hi d␤»
timotimo or something like
timotimo m: for <a b c d> { last when "c"; say "hi $_" }
camelia cbb5ee5f9: OUTPUT: «hi a␤hi b␤»
timotimo the $i++ can be done with the .kv method
timotimo m: for <a b c d>.kv -> $k, $v { say "k is $k, v is $v. yay!" }
camelia cbb5ee5f9: OUTPUT: «k is 0, v is a. yay!␤k is 1, v is b. yay!␤k is 2, v is c. yay!␤k is 3, v is d. yay!␤»

Answer (score 7):

## A generic explanation of the error message

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ...
```

When you see a `SORRY!`, then you know the compiler is talking to you about a problem that happened during compilation, even before there was an attempt to run your code.

```
Two terms in a row
```

This is the compiler's English summary of about what stopped it compiling your code. We'll return to it later.

The `------>` is the compiler's way of saying that it was confused by what you've written and it's going to display some of your code after the `------>`.

The `⏏`, a character whose Unicode name is `EJECT SYMBOL`, is inserted into the display of your code. The point it's inserted should help in interpreting the error message.

In this case it points between `.say` and `"VERBOSE..."`. The compiler thinks those are two terms in a row.

## What is a term?

Consider the following code:

```
start-time + 42
sum(start-time, 42)
```

Terms are somewhat like [terms in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_%28logic%29). Both the example expressions include the terms `start-time` and `42`. The overall expression `start-time + 42` is also a term. The expression `sum(start-time, 42)` might be called the `sum()` term or `sum(...)` term.

Terms are also somewhat like [nouns or noun phrases in natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminology). `start-time` and `42` are like nouns, hence terms. `start-time + 42` and `sum(...)` are like noun phrases, each of which is also a term.

(Btw, terms, in the sense relevant to this question, are *not* related to parsing "terminals" which are sometimes called "terms".)

By now you might be able to guess what happens if you try to compile the example code this section began with:

```
Two terms in a row across lines (missing semicolon or comma?)
```

The first line (`start-time + 42`) is a term. `sum(start-time, 42)` is another term. And there's nothing between them except a line end. Raku clearly doesn't like two terms in a row without something that's not a term in between them and whitespace and line ends don't count.

## How can one avoid the "Two terms in a row" error?

Operators like the infix `+`, postcircumfix `()`, and infix `,` that I used in the above examples can be used in operator positions (before, after, in between, or around, terms) to form expressions. (And the overall expressions are then themselves terms as explained above.)

Keywords like `for` or `last`, used in keyword position, are also *not* terms (unless you are crazy enough to redefine them as terms, in which case you'll likely get the weird compilation errors you deserve. :)) But, like operators, they must be placed in the right position or the compiler might think they're terms. If you write `last` in the wrong place, the compiler might think `last` is a term.

## The problem with your code

The compiler considers `.say`  (note the space at the end) to be a term, equivalent to `.say()`. So it interprets what you wrote as `.say() "VERBOSE..."` which is two terms in a row.

(I recommend you just accept that this is so but if you wish to dig into the minutia of method calling syntax to fully understand why `invocant.foo ( arrgh, arrgh, ... ) ;` is also "Two terms in a row", see [my answer covering various syntaxes related to routine calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50283014/1077672).)

Let's fix your code by changing the `.say` to `say` (without the `.`):

```
say "VERBOSE \"$_ is the string\"" for $*IN.lines() last when "";
```

The compiler returns another "Two terms in a row" error but now it points between `$*IN.lines()` and `last`.

The `for` keyword and its iteration argument have to be either at the start of a statement or at the end of a statement. You've used them at the end.

But that means that what comes after the `for` is a term (its iteration argument).

`$*IN.lines()` can work as a term.

You could even have it be part of an expression, eg. `for flat $*IN.lines(), $*FOO.lines()` to loop over both input lines and lines from some other handle. (The `flat` creates a single list for the `for` to loop over by flattening the two individual lists, one from `$*IN.lines()`, the other from `$*FOO.lines()`.)

But you didn't build an expression, you just immediately followed `$*IN.lines()` with `last`.

Because there isn't a `last` infix operator, and `last` must be the first word in a statement for it to be interpreted as the keyword `last`, the compiler instead interprets the `last` as a term -- and so it sees "Two terms in a row".

You need the `last` to be a statement keyword, and it needs to be in the context of the `for` loop. But you already have a statement in the context of the `for` loop, namely the `say ...` expression/term. You need some brackets or similar to allow you to write multiple statements. Here's one way:

```
{ last when ""; say "VERBOSE \"$_ is the string\""; $i=$i+1 } for $*IN.lines();
```

Now your code works.

## Final tweaks

I might as well throw in a couple final tweaks:

```
( last when ''; say qq[VERBOSE "$_ is the string"]; $i++ ) for lines ;
```

- I've switched from `{...}` to `(...)`. It's not more compact but it shows that you can use parens rather than braces when the `for` is written as a statement modifier (i.e. at the end of the statement rather than at the start). The `{...}` create a lexical scope whereas `(...)` does not; there are times where one or the other is just what you need.
- You don't need the `$*IN.` because there's a `lines` sub that's equivalent to `$*IN.lines()`.
- I've dropped the `()` after `lines` because they're not needed if there are no arguments after `lines` (or `$*IN.lines`) and before the end of the statement.
- I've used `''` instead of `""` because I think it's a good habit to use non-interpolating quotes if you don't need interpolating ones.
- I've used `qq[...]` because that means you don't have to escape the `"` in the string.
- I've used `$i++` rather than `$i=$i+1` because it achieves the same effect and I think it reads better.