# How to use hyperoperators with Scalars that aren't really scalar?

Tags: raku, rakudo

I want to make a hash of sets. Well, SetHashes, since they need to be mutable.

In fact, I would like to initialize my Hash with multiple identical copies of the same SetHash.

I have an array containing the keys for the new hash: `@keys`

And I have my SetHash already initialized in a scalar variable: `$set`

I'm looking for a clean way to initialize the hash.

This works:

```
my %hash = ({ $_ => $set.clone } for @keys);
```

(The parens are needed for precedence; without them, the assignment to `%hash` is part of the body of the `for` loop. I could change it to a non-postfix for loop or make any of several other minor changes to get the same result in a slightly different way, but that's not what I'm interested in here.)

Instead, I was kind of hoping I could use one of Raku's nifty hyper-operators, maybe like this:

```
my %hash = @keys »=>» $set;
```

That expression works a treat when `$set` is a simple string or number, but a SetHash?

```
Array >>=>>> SetHash can never work reliably: order of keys in SetHash is indeterminate
```

Good to know, but I don't want it to hyper over the RHS, in *any* order. That's why I used the right-pointing version of the hyperop: so it would instead replicate the RHS as needed to match it up to the LHS. In this sort of expression, is there any way to say "Yo, Raku, treat this as a scalar. No, really."?

I tried an explicit Scalar wrapper (which would make the values harder to get at, but it was an experiment):

```
my %map = @keys »=>» $($set,)
```

And that got me this message:

```
Lists on either side of non-dwimmy hyperop of infix:«=>» are not of the same length while recursing
left: 1 elements, right: 4 elements
```

So it has apparently recursed into the list on the left and found a single key and is trying to map it to a set on the right which has 4 elements. Which is what I want - the key mapped to the set. But instead it's mapping it to the *elements* of the set, and the hyperoperator is pointing the wrong way for that combination of sizes.

So why is it recursing on the right at all? I thought a Scalar container would prevent that. The documentation says it prevents flattening; how is this recursion not flattening? What's the distinction being drawn?

The error message says the version of the hyperoperator I'm using is "non-dwimmy", which may explain why it's not in fact doing what I mean, but is there maybe an even-less-dwimmy version that lets me be even more explicit?  I still haven't gotten my brain aligned well enough with the way Raku works for it to be able to tell WIM reliably.

Comment: ["RFC: Allow use of hyperoperators with an `Associative` that does not do `Iterable` role instead of dying with "can never work reliably"](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm looking for a clean way to initialize the hash.

One idiomatic option:

```
my %hash = @keys X=> $set;
```

See [`X` metaoperator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-X_(cross_metaoperator)).

---

> The documentation says ... a `Scalar` container ... prevents flattening; how is this recursion not flattening? What's the distinction being drawn?

A cat is an animal, but an animal is not necessarily a cat. Flattening may act recursively, but some operations that act recursively don't flatten. Recursive flattening stops if it sees a `Scalar`. But hyperoperation isn't flattening. I get where you're coming from, but this is not the real problem, or at least not a solution.

---

I had thought that hyperoperation had two tests controlling recursing:

- **Is it hyperoperating a [`nodal`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is%20nodal) operation (eg `.elems`)?** If so, just apply it like a parallel shallow `map` (so don't recurse). (The current doc quite strongly implies that `nodal` can only be usefully applied to a *method*, and only a `List` one (or augmentation thereof) rather than any routine that might get hyperoperated. That is much more restrictive than I was expecting, and I'm sceptical of its truth.)
- **Otherwise, is a value `Iterable`?** If so, then recurse into that value. In general the value of a `Scalar` automatically behaves as the value it contains, and that applies here. So `Scalar`s won't help.

---

A `SetHash` doesn't do the `Iterable` role. So I think this refusal to hyperoperate with it is something else.

---

I just searched the source and that yields two matches in the current Rakudo source, both in the Hyper module, with [this one](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/aba90b014be1e7b05afffea00dcad5169d29d471/src/core.c/Hyper.pm6#L77-L80) being the specific one we're dealing with:

```
    multi method infix(List:D \left, Associative:D \right) {
        die "{left.^name} $.name {right.^name} can never work reliably..."
    }
```

For some reason hyperoperation explicitly rejects use of `Associative`s on either the right or left when coupled with the other side being a `List` value.

---

Having pursued the "blame" (tracking who made what changes) I arrived at [the commit "Die on Associative `<<op>>` Iterable"](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/1b7253dfc62975090bfe35fde918f336c27d5353) which says:

> This can never work due to the random order of keys in the `Associative`.
> This used to die before, but with a very LTA error about a `Pair.new()`
> not finding a suitable candidate.

---

Perhaps this behaviour could be refined so that the determining factor is, first, whether an operand does the `Iterable` role, and then if it does, and is `Associative`, it dies, but if it isn't, it's accepted as a single item?

A [search for "can never work reliably" in GH/rakudo/rakudo issues](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%22can+never+work+reliably%22) yields zero matches.

Maybe file an issue? (**Update** I filed ["RFC: Allow use of hyperoperators with an Associative that does not do Iterable role instead of dying with "can never work reliably"](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4121).)

---

For now we need to find some *other* technique to stop a non-`Iterable` `Associative` being rejected. Here I use a [`Capture`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Capture) literal:

```
my %hash = @keys »=>» \($set);
```

This yields: `{a => \(SetHash.new("b","a","c")), b => \(SetHash.new("b","a","c")), ...`.

---

Adding a custom op unwraps en passant:

```
sub infix:« my=> » ($lhs, $rhs) { $lhs => $rhs[0] }
my %hash = @keys »my=>» \($set);
```

This yields the desired outcome: `{a => SetHash(a b c), b => SetHash(a b c), ...`.

---

```
my %hash = ({ $_ => $set.clone } for @keys);
```

> (The parens seem to be needed so it can tell that the curlies are a block instead of a `Hash` literal...)

No. That particular code in curlies is a `Block` regardless of whether it's in parens or not.

More generally, Raku code of the form `{...}` in term position is almost always a `Block`.

For an explanation of when a `{...}` sequence is a `Hash`, and how to force it to be one, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102980/1077672) to the Raku SO **Is that a `Hash` or a `Block`?**.

---

Without the parens you've written this:

```
my %hash = { block of code } for @keys
```

which attempts to iterate `@keys`, running the code `my %hash = { block of code }` for each iteration. The code fails because you can't assign a block of code to a hash.

Putting parens around the `({ block of code } for @keys)` part completely alters the meaning of the code.

Now it *runs* the block of code for each iteration. And it *concatenates* the result of each run into a list of results, each of which is a `Pair` generated by the code `$_ => $set.clone`. Then, when the `for` iteration has completed, that resulting list of pairs is assigned, once, to `my %hash`.

Comment: @MarkReed I've done every test I could with `dd()` and `.raku.say for ...` and AFAIK the `%hash`-es created by `my %hash = @keys X=> $set;` and `my %hash = ({ $_ => $set.clone } for @keys);` are identical. @raiph are you suggesting they're not? Or that they're (both) an incorrect specification? [I'm on Rakudo 2021.06].

Comment: Hi @jubilatious1 Given that `my %hash = @keys X=> $set` was my answer, I'd say I was unquestionably suggesting it was correct! Similarly Mark and their `my %hash = ({ $_ => $set.clone } for @keys)`, which they explicitly said "works". I presume what confused you is that Mark originally wrote "parens seem to be needed *so [Raku] can tell that the curlies are a block*", which was incorrect, and then Mark later edited their Q to remove that bit, which I didn't spot, so didn't edit my answer accordingly. I could remove that part from my answer, but I currently think it seems like a useful tidbit.